# Andromda and .Net Web Service

Tags: .net, web-services, code-generation

Im starting a new project in .net and i want to used andromda framework for code generation, i had used andromda for J2EE code generation and it works great for me, but reading at Andromda site could see that it works with .net as well, so i decided to used for my new project but i couldnt find an web services implementation with it, based on andromda .net documentation it is possible to do that, by any one have any clue about how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that i found to do this, was generating the entire project with andromda, even the web project and then at the web project create manually my web services which implements my androMDA service interface.

```
public class FriendlyTrafficService : System.Web.Services.WebService,
Com.Smarter.FriendlyTraffic.Service.IAdministrationService
```

and then a use the web service implemetation as a proxy to my real service implementation which is located in AdministrationServiceImpl.

Hope this help